# Error trying to compile hello world using cython and mingw

Tags: python, gcc, mingw, cython

I have already spent 2 days and tried everything else Ive seen on this site. Im trying to get cython to compile the basic helloworld script in python, but having errors. Gcc doesnt seem to be able to see the python header files despite the fact that the path listed is correct and I have verified that the files are there (for example c:/Python27/include/pyconfig.h) I have included the files used an my setup.

### helloWorld.pyx

```
print 'Hello World'
```

### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloWorld.pyx")
)
```

### cmd line

python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32

### Error

> Compiling helloworld.pyx because it changed. Cythonizing
>   helloworld.pyx running build_ext building 'helloworld' extension
>   C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include
>   -IC:\Pytho n27\PC -c helloworld.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\helloworld.o In file included from
>   helloworld.c:8: C:/Python27/include/pyconfig.h:68:16: io.h: No such
>   file or directory C:/Python27/include/pyconfig.h:296:20: stdio.h: No
>   such file or directory In file included from
>   C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/include/limits.h:122 , from
>   C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/include/syslimits.h: 7, from
>   C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/include/limits.h:11, from
>   C:/Python27/include/Python.h:19, from helloworld.c:16:
>   /mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/include/limits.h:122:61: limits.h: No
>   such file or directory In file included from helloworld.c:16:
>   C:/Python27/include/Python.h:35:5: #error "Python.h requires that
>   stdio.h define NULL." C:/Python27/include/Python.h:38:20: string.h: No
>   such file or directory C:/Python27/include/Python.h:40:19: errno.h: No
>   such file or directory C:/Python27/include/Python.h:42:20: stdlib.h:
>   No such file or directory C:/Python27/include/Python.h:56:20:
>   assert.h: No such file or directory In file included from
>   C:/Python27/include/Python.h:58, from helloworld.c:16:
>   C:/Python27/include/pyport.h:325:76: math.h: No such file or directory
>   C:/Python27/include/pyport.h:338:18: time.h: No such file or directory
>   C:/Python27/include/pyport.h:390:22: sys/stat.h: No such file or
>   directory In file included from C:/Python27/include/Python.h:80, from
>   helloworld.c:16: C:/Python27/include/object.h:307: error: syntax error
>   before "FILE" C:/Python27/include/object.h:459: error: syntax error
>   before "FILE" In file included from C:/Python27/include/Python.h:85,
>   from helloworld.c:16: C:/Python27/include/unicodeobject.h:57:19:
>   ctype.h: No such file or directory
>   C:/Python27/include/unicodeobject.h:120:21: wchar.h: No such file or
>   directory In file included from C:/Python27/include/Python.h:108, from
>   helloworld.c:16: C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:12: error: syntax
>   error before "FILE" C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:12: warning: no
>   semicolon at end of struct or union
>   C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:15: error: syntax error before '*'
>   token C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:33: error: syntax error before
>   '}' token C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:33: warning: type defaults
>   to `int' in declaration of`PyFileObject'
>   C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:33: warning: data definition has no
>   type or storage class C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:44: error:
>   syntax error before '*' token C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:45:
>   error: syntax error before '*' token
>   C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:46: error: syntax error before '*'
>   token C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:46: warning: type defaults to
>   `int' in declaration of PyFile_AsFile'
>   C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:46: warning: data definition has no
>   type or storage class C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:47: error:
>   syntax error before '*' token C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:48:
>   error: syntax error before '*' token
>   C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:65: error: syntax error before "FILE"
>   C:/Python27/include/fileobject.h:66: error: syntax error before "FILE"
>   In file included from C:/Python27/include/Python.h:127, from
>   helloworld.c:16: C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:35: error: syntax
>   error before '*' token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:36: error:
>   syntax error before '*' token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:38:
>   error: syntax error before '*' token
>   C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:39: error: syntax error before '*'
>   token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:40: error: syntax error before
>   '*' token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:45: error: syntax error
>   before '*' token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:55: error: syntax
>   error before '*' token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:61: error:
>   syntax error before '*' token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:78:
>   error: syntax error before '*' token
>   C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:152: error: syntax error before '*'
>   token C:/Python27/include/pythonrun.h:154: error: syntax error before
>   '*' token In file included from C:/Python27/include/Python.h:129, from
>   helloworld.c:16: C:/Python27/include/sysmodule.h:12: error: syntax
>   error before '*' token C:/Python27/include/sysmodule.h:12: error:
>   syntax error before "FILE" C:/Python27/include/sysmodule.h:12:
>   warning: type defaults to`int' in declaration of `PySys_GetFile'
>   C:/Python27/include/sysmodule.h:12: warning: data definition has no
>   type or storage class In file included from
>   C:/Python27/include/Python.h:131, from helloworld.c:16:
>   C:/Python27/include/import.h:39: error: syntax error before "FILE"
>   helloworld.c: In function`__PYX_NAN': helloworld.c:315: warning:
>   implicit declaration of function `memset' helloworld.c: In function`
>   __Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString': helloworld.c:1423: warning: implicit
>   declaration of function `strlen' helloworld.c: In function`
>   __Pyx_PyObject_AsStringAndSize': helloworld.c:1474: warning: implicit
>   declaration of function `assert' error: command
>   'C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

Comment: It looks like it is finding the Python headers and failing to find the C standard library headers. Are you sure that your installation of MinGW is actually working?

Answer (score 1):

As IanH commented, it looks like GCC is failing to find the standard C headers included in the Python headers, rather than an issue with Cython. Can you compile a simple C program, such as the one below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

To compile:

`$ gcc hello.c -o hello.exe`

Comment: You are correct. Here is my output: hello.c:1:19: stdio.h: No such file or directory. But gcc -v works. So?

Comment: Try reinstalling MinGW (+ msys if you're using it).